# jquery div slide effect with another div adjusting width automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying the giva a menu slides in/out effect to give the main content more space whenever user wants - More like the Google Calendar hamburger menu click behaviour.

I am trying to have two divs side-by-side. 1st is menu, 2nd is other content. Using jQuery UI I am trying toggle slide the 1st div.

Two issues -

1. Only when I give fixed width to 2nd div, I am able to place them side-by-side.

   How to make the second div takes rest of the space?
2. Only after completion of the slide-out 2nd div adjust its width.

   How to make increase the width smoothly?

Here is the code https://codepen.io/coder92/pen/Yjomwd

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //adds click function to the hamburger menu
 $( "#menu" ).click(function() {
  $(".menuDiv").toggle('slide');
 });
 });
```

```css
.menuDiv{
  background-color: green;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
}
.contentDiv{
  //width:100%;
  width:500px;
  color:white;
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<span id="menu"> toggle </span>

<div>
  <div class="menuDiv">
    Menu
  </div>
  <div class="contentDiv">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> data </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For the smooth sliding you can use

- `$(".menuDiv").animate({width: 'toggle'}, 350);`

And to make the data take up the rest of the page

- Remove `float: left;` from `.contentDiv` (Float makes the element not take full size)
- Add `margin: 0 auto;` (This makes the data take the full rest of the page)
- Add `overflow: hidden` (this stops the blue from going under the green)

Check it out: **https://codepen.io/Funce/pen/QBeLOr**

Comment: Thanks Funce. This works. Just to fix menu div text getting wrapped I could use js suggested by Chan MT

Answer (score 1):

The way Google Calendar do it is to utilize a combination of `flex` display, `hidden` overflow and negative `margin` to achieve the effect. You may refer to the sample below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //adds click function to the hamburger menu
    $("#menu").click(function () {
       var $menu = $(".menuDiv");
       if ($menu.is(':visible')) {
            $menu.animate({'margin-left':-200}, function() {
                $menu.hide();
            });
        } else {
            $menu.show().animate({'margin-left':0});
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.containerDiv {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.menuDiv{
  background-color: green;
  width:200px;
}
.contentDiv{
  color:white;
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<span id="menu"> toggle </span>

<div class="containerDiv">
  <div class="menuDiv">
    Menu
  </div>
  <div class="contentDiv">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td> data </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I use the jQuery `animate` method, while Google Calendar use the CSS `transition` for theirs.